# Javascript and ascii homework

Tags: javascript, html, ascii

I have an assignment where I have to select an animation and run it. It works except the turbo function doesnt work like its suppose to and I'm not sure how to change the font size here is the link http://turing.plymouth.edu/~besopko/hw6/ascii.html

My php is:

```
var frameStr;
var frameSeq;
var currentFrame;
var frameanime;
var q;
var startspeed = 250;

function startFunction(){
  frameStr = document.getElementById("Frame").value;
  if(frameStr.indexOf("\r\n")!=-1){
    frameSeq = frameStr.split("=====\r\n");
  }
  else{
    frameSeq = frameStr.split("=====\n");
    currentFrame = 0;
    q = setInterval(NextFrame, startspeed);
  }
}

function AnimeFunction(){
 frameanime = document.getElementById("animation").value;
  if(frameanime == "EXERCISE"){
    $("Frame").value = EXERCISE;  
  }
  else if(frameanime == "JUGGLER"){
    $("Frame").value = JUGGLER;
  }
  else if(frameanime == "BIKE"){
    $("Frame").value = BIKE;
  }
  else if(frameanime == "DIVE"){
    $("Frame").value = DIVE;
  }
  else if(frameanime == "CUSTOM"){
    $("Frame").value = CUSTOM;
  }
}

function NextFrame(){
  document.getElementById("Frame").value = frameSeq[currentFrame];
  currentFrame = (currentFrame+1)% frameSeq.length;
}

function stopFunction(){
  clearInterval(q);
}

//this function isn't working properly
function turboFunction(){
  var speed = document.getElementById("speed1");
  if(speed.checked){
    startspeed = 50;
    q = setInterval(nextFrame, startspeed);
  }
  else {
    startspeed = 250;
    q = setInterval(nextFrame, startspeed);
  }

}
function sizeFunction(){
 text = document.getElementById("size").value;
 if(text == "tiny"){
 $("Frame").value = //stuck here;
}

}
```

I'm not sure why the `turboFunction()` is working incorrectly and I'm not exactly sure how to change the font size of the ascii animation. Any input would be very helpful.

Comment: Your code is badly formatted :-(   You might want to work on that, it would make it easier to read.

Comment: It's just the way I posted it, this is my first post I wasn't really sure how to just copy and past my code :\

Comment: Click on edit.  There are some helps  in a nut shell code should not have anything on the line before it, should be indented 4 spaces I think (the help will tell you) and use the `tick's` around short code you want greyed out.

Comment: Wow, your PHP looks a lot like JavaScript.

Comment: ***1*** "turbo function doesnt work like its suppose to" - How _should_ it work? ***2*** "how to change the font size?" - look at line 62 of `ascii.js` (Hint: learn how to better use your browser's debugger.) ***3*** Please, ask a question in future. (You only implied a couple this time. What may seem perfectly obvious to you, may not be to others - asking an explicit question avoids the ambiguity)